# How to know if there are non-whitespace char before the target string?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do i express this in regex to know if there are non-whitespace chars before '#include'?

```
var kword_search = "#include<iostream.>something";
/^?+\s*#include$/.test(kword_search)//must return false

var kword_search = "asffs#include<iostream.>something";
/^?+\s*#include$/.test(kword_search)//must return true
```

Not really good in regex

Comment: If you have accepted one of these answers, please mark as answered.

Comment: @hnwd - sorry, i forgot to get back to this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely looking for something like `/^[\S ]#include/`

Explanation:

```
 ^                         beginning of the string
  [\S ]                    any character of: non-whitespace (all but
                           \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), ' '
   #include/               '#include/'
```

Regex quick reference

```
[abc]      A single character: a, b or c
[^abc]     Any single character but a, b, or c
[a-z]      Any single character in the range a-z
[a-zA-Z]   Any single character in the range a-z or A-Z
^          Start of line
$          End of line
\A         Start of string
\z         End of string
.          Any single character
\s         Any whitespace character
\S         Any non-whitespace character
\d         Any digit
\D         Any non-digit
\w         Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
\W         Any non-word character
\b         Any word boundary character
(...)      Capture everything enclosed
(a|b)      a or b
?          Zero or one
*          Zero or more
+          One or more
```

Comment: btw why do i need to enclosed it in []?

Comment: It's considered using a character class, such as multiple regex's. In this case doubt you need it, but I put it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Use negated character class, with appropriate quantifier. And remove the `$` anchor from the end, your string doesn't end with `include`:

```
/^[^\s]+#include/.test(kword_search)
```

Comment: @fireflieslive. Can you post the strings it is not working for?

Comment: This wouldn't work on lines with both whitespace and non-whitespace characters before the `#include`, which it sounds like the OP wants. Try something like `^[^#]*[^\s#][^#]*#include`

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
\S#include
```

See a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b0hem1an/rRtAq/9446/) passing your tests on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:\s*|)#include/.test(kword_search)
```